# Refreshing list using combineLatest: Angular2 + RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, combinelatest

I have a component in which I am displaying a table of data (users) generated from an http request to an API. There are a variety of filters on the table so I generate the table data as follows:

```
this.displayUsers$ = Observable.combineLatest(
            this.users$,
            this.siteFilter$,
            this.clientFilter$,
            this.activeFilter$,
            this.nameFilter$
        )
            .map(([users, siteFilter, clientFilter, activeFilter, nameFilter]) => {
                console.log("Users changed? ", users);
                if (siteFilter === null
                    && clientFilter === null
                    && activeFilter === null
                    && nameFilter.length < 1) {
                    return users;
                }
                return users
                    .filter(user => {
                        // manipulate users array based on filters
                    })
            });
```

The `xFilter$`s are BehaviorSubjects that emit new values in response to changes to their inputs in the template. `users$` is assigned as follows:

```
this.users$ = this.userService.getList();
```

Where `getList()` returns an http request to get a list of users.

The list successfully updates whenever the filters are changed, but I have issues when I need to update the list with fresh users. For example, a user can perform CRUD operations on the table of users (ie delete a user). When the user is deleted, however, the table does not update to reflect this change. The method I am currently using to (try) to fresh the table is by calling a refresh function in the success callback of the delete operation:

```
refreshUserList() {
        console.log("Refreshing user list");
        this.users$ = this.userService.getList();
    }
```

Despite calling this after the operation is complete, the combineLatest observable does not get 'triggered' again and the list data remains stale. Is there a better way to refresh data generated by combineLatest with http requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that in the case of user list update your users$ observable does not emit any new value. You have to make it do so.

This is skeleton of an idea how to fix it:

```
const updateUsersTrigger = new Subject<void>();

this.displayUsers$ = Observable.combineLatest(
    // switchMap() will re-subscribe to this.userService.getList() observable on each emit from updateUsersTrigger
    // thus making http requests each time when user list should be updated.
    updateUsersTrigger.startWith(null).switchMap(() => this.userService.getList()),
    this.siteFilter$,
    this.clientFilter$,
    this.activeFilter$,
    this.nameFilter$
)
    .map(([users, siteFilter, clientFilter, activeFilter, nameFilter]) => {

    .......

});

// this will trigger user list update
updateUsersTrigger.next();
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thanks for the suggestion. I think I'm missing something with my implementation, however, because now I'm getting no table data (even when I change filters). I changed refreshUserList() { updateUsersTrigger.next(); } and call this in ngOnInit() but still no luck.

Comment: @natmegs, try something like this: `updateUsersTrigger.startWith(null).switchMap(() => ... call service ...)` instead of emitting something in ngOnInit() - I wouldn't expect it to work actually, I think it fires too early.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to comment yet, so I'll write here and correct me if I'm wrong or if this is out of the question. If you use `.splice()` on successful delete to update the DOM instead of sending another http request, wouldn't that be easier and less straining on the client?

Comment: Either way OP needs some observable to emit new array, be it http request or splice() result in some Observable.map() or something else.